# Explanation of a proof about graded module structure

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $\Bbb F$ be a field and $M$ a finitely generated $\Bbb F[x]$-module.  The structure theorem for modules over a PID says that
$$
M\cong \Bbb F[x]^r\oplus\biggl(\bigoplus_{j=0}^s\Bbb F[x]/(f_j(x))\biggr)\text,
$$
where $r$ and $s$ are non-negative integers and $f_j(x)$ are polynomials in $\Bbb F[x]$.

Now, because  the ring $\Bbb F[x]$ is graded by the standard grading $\Bbb F[x]=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i\Bbb F$, according to this [paper](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/WangK.pdf) (Theorem 4.8.), $M$ can be written also in the form
$$
M\cong\biggl(\bigoplus_{i=1}^M(x^{a_i})\biggr)\oplus\biggl(\bigoplus_{j=1}^N(x^{b_j})/(x^{c_j})\biggr)
$$
for some non-negative integers $M,N$, $a_i,b_j,c_j$.

I can't understand this sentence from the proof:

> The  free  component  is  composed  of  graded  rings  of  the  form $\bigoplus_{i\geq q}x^i\Bbb F$
>   , which are isomorphic to ideals of the form $(x^q)$.

The free part is $\Bbb F[x]^r$: How can I write this as a direct sum of things of the form $\bigoplus_{i\geq q}x^i\Bbb F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free part is a direct sum of shifted copies of $\mathbb F[X]$. That is, $\mathbb F[X](-k)$ for some $k\ge 0$. This is nothing but $X^k\mathbb F[X]$.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $\Bbb F[x](-k)$?  I can't understand how the sum could be direct if the summands overlap

Comment: Notation is explained e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181743/notation-for-free-graded-resolutions-of-graded-modules).

Comment: Btw, you got a long explanation of the shifting phenomenon in a former question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610978/decomposition-of-a-graded-module

Comment: Now I understand the notation $\Bbb F[x](-k)$ which is the same as $\Sigma^k\Bbb F[x]$ of my other question, but I still can't understand the direct sum.  If the free part has rank 1, then it is $\Bbb F[x]$ which is the same as $\Bbb F[x](-0)$.  But if, for example, the free part has rank 2, $\Bbb F[x]\oplus \Bbb F[x]$, how can I write it in terms of $\Bbb F[x](-k)$'s?  What are the values of $k$?

Comment: The shifts appear as follows: if $M$ is free of rank one and the homogeneous generator is $z$ with $\deg z=d>0$, then $M\simeq \mathbb F[X](-d)$. Why? Because the (iso)morphisms of graded modules are usually graded, that is, send $n$th degree part into  $n$th degree part. In the example above, $1\mapsto e$ is not a graded morphism since $\deg 1=0$ and $\deg z=d$. Then you have to make $\deg 1=d$ by moving it $d$ places to the right. This means to consider $\mathbb F[X](-d)$ which has $\mathbb F[X](-d)_n=\mathbb F[X]_{n-d}$, that is,

Comment: $\mathbb F[X](-d)=0\oplus\cdots\oplus 0\oplus F\oplus FX\oplus\cdots$ ($0$ appears $d$ times).

Comment: In the above comment should be $1\mapsto z$ instead of $1\mapsto e$.

Comment: Consider $M\cong \Bbb F[x]^r$, where $M$ is a graded module, and call $\psi:\Bbb F[x]^r\to M$ the isomorphism (a normal isomorphism, not a graded one).  Let's call $m_i:=\psi(e_i)$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis elements of $\Bbb F[x]^r$.  From what I can understand, in order to grade $\Bbb F[x]^r$ and write it as a sum of shifted copies of $\Bbb F[x]$ one have to assign to each $e_i$ the degree of the corresponding element $m_i$.  But how can I know each $m_i$ is homogeneous?

Comment: In fact you can always choose a homogeneous basis for $M$. This is proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1543392/121097) in a more general setting. (As you can see, everything you need is on this site. Just need to search for this a little.)

Comment: Thank you!  Now I think I understand the decomposition.  When it is possible I will bounty your answer, for the effort you put in answering all my comments